# Change location if LocalStorage value is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

I have a login page. After login I store the user value into session storage like

```
localStorage.setItem("user", something);
```

After successful login I change the `$location.path('/something')`. In this page I assign `$scope.user=localStorage.getItem("user")`. If suppose user delete the history and reload the successful login page (`/something`) I getting error.

I tried like:

```
if (!localStorage.getItem("user")) {
    $scope.$apply(function(){
        $location.path('/');
    })
}
```

But it's not working. How can I solve this?

Comment: I see 2 issues in your code. Misspelling in $locaion.path('/something') - should be $location.path('/something'). The second - localStorage can store only strings, so you should stringify and parse JSON to work with localStorage.

Comment: @ Mikalai.  thanks for finding typos. but this is not my actual code. actual one is bit lengthier. in my actual code there is no typo and also i store the string using JSON.stringify.

Comment: $scope.$apply(function(){
        $location.path('/');
    }) - here you don't need $apply

Comment: both way  i have tried but its not working

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
if(typeof localStorage.getItem("user") === 'undefined') {
  //do redirect
}
```

Comment: checking is Not a Problem. it (!localStorage.getItem("user")) alerts true. when user clear history and reload the page.